# Where can I find H. Ishii's expository papers that appeared on Sugaku Expositions (1996 and 1997)?

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, soft-question

I'm looking for two papers written by H. Ishii:

- *Viscosity solutions of nonlinear partial differential equations*, Sugaku Expositions 9 (1996), no. 2, pp. 135--152 (English).
- *Viscosity solutions and their applications*, Sugaku Expositions 10 (1997), no. 2, 123--141 (English).

The library of my institution doesn't seem to be able to find a copy of the issues of the journal.

Does anyone know if there is a copy of these two papers available online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Viscosity solutions and their applications](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266365761_Viscosity_solutions_and_their_applications) is online via ResearchGate (and you can even read it without become a member, which is good). The other paper, [Viscosity solutions of nonlinear partial differential equations](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267107400_Viscosity_solutions_of_nonlinear_partial_differential_equations), would require you to join Researchgate... I would avoid that and just contact [prof. Ishii](http://www.edu.waseda.ac.jp/~ishii/) directly.